# How to mount external Linux hard drive on Ubuntu?

Tags: external-hdd

I have an external hard drive of Linux. How do I see the files from Ubuntu system?
I also need to transfer these files to MAC system from Ubuntu system.

Comment: Simply connect the drive and click its icon in your file manager, e.g. nautilus or dolphin, they should automatically mount it.

Comment: If transferring to Mac, you may have to format the drive on the Mac.  Pretty sure Mac doesn't read ext drives, but Linux reads some/most (all?) Mac formatted drives.  Web-search to find which format is best for your situation.

Comment: If it doesn't appear in File Manager when you plug the drive in, that's going to be a lot more difficult.  Could be a bad cable, no power, unreadable file system... lots of things.

Answer (score 4):

Normally, provided the drive is not encrypted and connected via USB, you plug it in and enjoy (On Linux). Macos cannot read regular Linux file systems.

If it is a SATA drive (connected via SATA in e.g. a tower), you would have to mount it.

You normally mount (make accessible) a hard drive  by issuing the following command on the command line:

```
sudo mount /dev/sdb1 /mnt
```

That command is assuming you have but two SATA drives (CD-ROM/DVD/BlueRay, Hard drive) in your system and /mnt is not used for mounting anything else (you would know). To access it, you access `/mnt`. If you have three, e.g. two hard drives and an optical disk (CD/DVD/BR), it would be `mount /dev/sdc1 /mnt`).

SATA devices live in `/dev/sd<some_letter>` and usually have one or more partitions `/dev/sd<some_letter><some_number>`. So, `/dev/sdb1` translates to the first partition of the second drive.

To get a list of all hard drives and partitions, you issue `fdisk -l` on the command line.

If it is SATA and encrypted, you would have to use the tools of program you used to encrypt it to mount it.

Comment: In some cases, it could be sdb and sdc. The rest of the command remains the same.

Answer (score 0):

It's actually quite simple, after you know how, that is:

```
sudo fdisk -l
```

will list all available drives and partitions. Find the drive/partition you want to mount, and run:

```
sudo mkdir /mnt/disk
sudo mount /dev/(insert disk/partition here) /mnt/disk
```

Comment: Will it keep this mount (And name) after a reboot? For example if I have a Docker image where I want to save data to that external drive, can I then config /mnt/*disk* and expect it to work after a reboot